# Nested ANDs in IF Statement

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function csvRange(myRange As Range)
    Dim csvRangeOutput
    Dim entry As Variant
    For Each entry In myRange
        If IsEmpty(entry.Value) Then
            Exit For
        ElseIf entry.offset(0, 11) > 1 _
        Or entry.offset(0, 12) > 1 _
        Or entry.offset(0, 13) > 1 And entry.offset(0, 13) = Not "NA" _
        Or entry.offset(0, 14) > 1 And entry.offset(0, 14) = Not "NA" Then
            csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & entry.Value & ","
        End If
    Next
    csvRange = Left(csvRangeOutput, Len(csvRangeOutput) - 1)
End Function
```

I have some issues with getting this piece of code to generate a comma separated list of cell entries with any of the 4 corresponding column offset values that fulfill both criteria:

1. value > 1
2. value not = "NA"

Right now, when I run this function under a given range of cells, I get #VALUE!

Comment: `= Not` ----> `<>`. You're likely missing some parentheses too.

Comment: Is it text "NA" or error `#NA`? If so you can use `cvErr`

Comment: the "NA" is text

Comment: Thanks BigBen, replacing = Not with <> and incorporating parenthesis around AND statements worked.